# Table inside table

Tags: tables, graphics

Inside of a Beamer presentation, I want to put a graph side-by-side with a data table. Outline of the code:

```
\begin{tabular*}{l r}
    \begin{center}\includegraphics{graph}\end{center}
    &
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
        4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\\hline
    \end{tabular}\\
\end{tabular*}
```

This gives the error `Something's wrong, maybe a missing \item`. Earlier in the presentation I used a `tabular*` environment to put a graph side-by-side with some bullet points, and in another slide, I used a `tabular` environment to display data under a graph. Is there a better way to do this? Why doesn't LaTeX allow a `tabular` inside a `tabular*`?

Comment: It does allow it. Remove the inner tabular: The error will stay. The problem is the \begin{center} which is not allowed in a column of type l as it is a list (and it doesn't make sense there anyway).

Comment: Beamer's `columns` environment might be more stable for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `columns` environment instead. You can use one column to place the image and another one for the table:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}    
  \centering
  \includegraphics{graph}
\column{.5\textwidth}    
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}\hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
        4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The line `\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}` was only included to make my example compilable for everyone; do not include it in your actual code.

Answer (score 6):

Do not use the `center` environment inside the table. IIRC it uses a `trivlist` internally and will add vertical spacing which is normally not wanted in this case. You could use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\includegraphics{graph}}` instead.

The `tabular` inside a `tabular` or `tabular*` should be OK. When in doubt just wrap the inner one inside braces `{ }`, but this should normally not be necessary.

The following minimal example works for me. However, centering the graph in such a table with only one row doesn't make sense. The cell is then anyway exactly the size of the graph. Only if there is more than one row it would make sense.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{%
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l r}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\includegraphics{graph}}
    &
    \begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\hline
        4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\\hline
    \end{tabular}\\
\end{tabular*}
}

\end{document}
```